# merge datasets based on time conditions

Tags: r

I have two datasets as follows:

```
df1 <- data.frame(
  Timestamp = as.POSIXct(c('2023-09-22 09:30:00', '2023-09-22 11:30:00', '2023-09-23 11:45:00', '2023-09-23 12:45:00')),
  group = c('A', 'A', 'B', 'B'))

df2 <- data.frame(
  Timestamp2 = as.POSIXct(c('2023-09-22 09:29:00', '2023-09-22 11:31:00', '2023-09-23 11:44:00', '2023-09-23 12:50:00')),
  group = c('A', 'A', 'B', 'B'),
  type = c('01', '33', '22', '98'))
```

I would like to identify which timestamps from df2 occur CLOSEST, and BEFORE, df1. I would then like to merge rows from df2 to df1 if the timestamp from df2 occurs closest and before df1. I would like to do this by group.

My desired output is as follows:

```
result <- data.frame(
  Timestamp = as.POSIXct(c('2023-09-22 09:30:00', '2023-09-22 11:30:00', '2023-09-22 11:45:00', '2023-09-22 12:45:00')),
  Timestamp2 = as.POSIXct(c('2023-09-22 09:29:00', '2023-09-22 9:29:00', '2023-09-23 
  11:44:00', '2023-09-23 11:44:00')),
  group = c('A', 'A', 'B', 'B'),
  type = c('01', '01', '22', '22'))
```

In this example, groups occur on different days so the grouping component doesn't matter, but with my real data, sometimes groups have the same timestamps so there would need to be a grouping component.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The `dplyr::*_join()` functions support fuzzy matching via `join_by()` ([learn more](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/join_by.html)).
Here is some code that works for your example using `closest()` from the `join_by()` DSL.

```r
library(dplyr)

inner_join(df1,
           df2,
           join_by(closest(Timestamp >= Timestamp2), group))
#>             Timestamp group          Timestamp2 type
#> 1 2023-09-22 09:30:00     A 2023-09-22 09:29:00   01
#> 2 2023-09-22 11:30:00     A 2023-09-22 09:29:00   01
#> 3 2023-09-23 11:45:00     B 2023-09-23 11:44:00   22
#> 4 2023-09-23 12:45:00     B 2023-09-23 11:44:00   22
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `difftime` in `outer`, then set negative difs to `Inf` and do `which.min` to subset `df2`. `cbind`.

```
o <- outer(df1$Timestamp, df2$Timestamp, difftime)
cbind(df1, df2[unlist(apply(o, 1, \(x) which.min(replace(x, x < 0, NA)))), ])
#               Timestamp group          Timestamp2 group type
# 1   2023-09-22 09:30:00     A 2023-09-22 09:29:00     A   01
# 1.1 2023-09-22 11:30:00     A 2023-09-22 09:29:00     A   01
# 3   2023-09-23 11:45:00     B 2023-09-23 11:44:00     B   22
# 3.1 2023-09-23 12:45:00     B 2023-09-23 11:44:00     B   22
```